# Regex only matching non-empty newlines

Tags: php, regex

I have a textarea where a user can enter text like this:

```
**Title 1**
aaa
bbb
ccc

**Title 2**
xxx
yyy
zzz
```

I convert it to the following result:

---

**Title 1**

> aaa
> bbb
> ccc

**Title 2**
> xxx
> yyy
> zzz

---

So:

- Everything between two asterixes gets converted to bold text
- Every new line gets a `>` placed before the line

The problem is that the result gets converted to this:

---

**Title 1**

> aaa
> bbb
> ccc
>

**Title 2**
> xxx
> yyy
> zzz 
>

---

Empty new lines also get a `>`... This should not be the case. How do I filter out all the empty new lines?

**Test code:**

```
<html>
    <style>
        .product-desc-section {
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 1em;
        }
    </style>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <textarea name="text"></textarea>
        <br><input type="submit" name="btnTest" value="test">
    </form>

    <?php 
        if (isset($_POST['btnTest'])) {
            $text = $_POST['text'];

            $text = preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", "\n", $text);
            $text = preg_replace('#\*{2}(.*?)\*{2}#', "<br><br><span class='product-desc-section'>$1</span>", htmlspecialchars($text));
            $text = preg_replace('~[\r\n]+~', "<br><span class='new-line'>&gt;&nbsp;</span>", $text);

            echo "<pre>".$text."</pre>";
        }
    ?>
</html>
```

**Test-input:**

```
**Title 1**
a
b
c

**Title 2**
x
y
z
```

**Output:**

---

**Title 1**

> a
> b
> c
>

**Title 2**
> x
> y
> z

---

**Expected output:**

---

**Title 1**

> a
> b
> c

**Title 2**
> x
> y
> z

---

How do I only place a `>`-icon on every new line which is not empty?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `<br>` in the first replacement calls.

One option could be matching all newlines asserting that it is not directly followed by a `<br>`

```
$text = preg_replace('~[\r\n]+(?!<br>)~', "<br><span class='new-line'>&gt;&nbsp;</span>", $text);
```

You might also use `\R+` instead of `[\r\n]+` to match any unicode newline sequence.